# Display all entry titles on one line during FOR loop

Tags: entries, forloop, loop

I have a FOR loop that should be displaying all the entry titles on one line. But instead, it is outputting them on separate lines.

I want to see:

```
Developer: Jane Doe, Jim Doe
```

Instead, I am getting:

```
Developer: Jane Doe
Developer: Jim Doe
```

My code:

```
{% set developers = entry.GamesDeveloper %}

{% for developer in developers %}
    <li>Developer: <a href="{{ developer.url }}">{{ developer.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're using an html list `<li>` element, which by default puts each element on a new line.  You could style away the newline I suppose, but why use it at all...there are a bunch of ways of doing this, but this is one simple one:

```
{% set developers = entry.GamesDeveloper %}
{% if developers|length %}
Developer: 
{% for developer in developers %}           
    <a href="{{ developer.url }}">{{ developer.title }}</a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I need to be able to keep it within a html list though. I have data before and after that will also b in a list. aka

Comment: Ok well then you need to style the list I guess - something like `li { display: inline; }` in your css should do it.

Comment: ...but you'll still need to put `Developer:` outside your for loop of course.  And if you want the commas check the `not loop.last` condition....